# Textwrap with hyphen

Tags: python, python-2.7, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap a list of strings. Strings are long and I want to break to lines with a limit of 70 characters using Textwrap. This part is easy, the problem is I want to add dash/hyphen at the end of created lines, but cannot figure out how to do it with textwrap

For example if line length is 2 and string is

```
abcdefgh
```

I want to obtain this

```
ab-
cd-
ef-
gh
```

The command I use is:

```
aq[i]=textwrap.fill(ap[i], 70)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try as below

```
ap = 'abcdefgh'
textwrap.fill(ap, 2).replace("\n","-\n")
```

output:
'ab-\ncd-\nef-\ngh'

End of the word will miss out `-`, so you can add explicitly again only for last word.